# using this inside a javascript onevent function

Tags: javascript, html

Why can't I access the current element using 'this' keyword in javascript? It works in jquery but I want to learn the vanilla javscript equivalent and I can't seem to find the answer.

```
      document.getElementById('icon').onclick = () => {
        this.style.display = 'none'
        console.log(this) // prints the window instead of element?
      }
```

Comment: Use a traditional function instead of arrow function.

Comment: Heh, this is the opposite of the problem I usually see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById('icon').onclick = ( ) => { 
         event.currentTarget.style.display='none';               
      }
```

```html
<div id='icon'>xxx</div>
```

Comment: Looks good, but add `event` var to function parameters

Comment: why? The code works as is.

Comment: where else is event declared at?  Your params are empty, but you can put event in there: (event) => { event.target... }

Comment: well I can, but why? I can access the event inside the function without passing it as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the function scope when using arrow functions.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

> An arrow function expression is a syntactically compact alternative to a regular function expression, although without its own bindings to the *this*, *arguments*, *super*, or *new.target* keywords. Arrow function expressions are ill suited as methods, and they cannot be used as constructors.

If you would like to use `this`, use `function(){...}` instead of `()=>{...}`

```
   document.getElementById('icon').onclick = function(){
  this.style.display = 'none'
  console.log(this) // prints the window instead of element?
}
```